# Android phone shutting off while using mediarecorder and cannot get logs

Tags: android

Im using the media recorder in a service. The media recorder will work fine for short calls, but when the call is about 5 min the phone will shut off and restart itself. Im not sure how to get the logs because i cant test the media recorder in the emulator and also whenever im debugging with usb connected to the phone it wont shut off. It only shuts off when its completely disconnected.

Ive tried to get the logs but when the phone shuts off the only logs i can receive when it comes back on is the logs for the phone starting up. Can anyone offer any insight or assistance in either getting the logs or even sharing any similar experiences or fixes with the media recorder.

Also I have an LG Optimus T with 2.2

Answer (score 1):

you can try using an app called "alogcat" and set it to record logs every few seconds to an SDcard.